# ASP.net Contact form without using SMTP?

Tags: asp.net, smtp, sendmail

I am basically looking for a solution to send a contact form over the web from a website written in asp.net without having to use smtp.  This seems like it should be a simple task however it has grown into a complex issue, I should state that asp.net is not my preferred method for building the site so I am not very familiar with sending emails using it, I would have much rather built the site in php.  Hosting company will not provide me the smtp server information and I do not have my own.  Below is the code I am trying right now:

```
Sub Send2Mail (sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

Dim objMail as New MailMessage()

    objMail.To = "email@email.com"
  objMail.From = strEmail.Text

  objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
  objMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
  objMail.Subject = strSubject.Text

  objMail.Body = "Name : " + strName.Text + vbNewLine + "Email : " + strEmail.text + vbnewLine + "Message : " + strYourMsg.text

  SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"
  SmtpMail.Send(objMail)


  strMessage.Visible = true

End Sub
```

Is there any alternative to using the SMTP server?

Comment: How would you have done the same task using PHP? It's not different here as far as sending the data on an email. BTW, your code looks ok to me. Are you getting any exceptions when you send the email? Are you sure `localhost` has an smtp server running locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually you will need access to an SMTP server in order to send the actual email, even if it's access via another SMTP host.

In the meantime you could store the data within a specific database table and have that checked regularly.

Initially this could be done manually, but once you have access to an SMTP server you could have the addition of new rows trigger an email.

One thing that you must protect against though is the use of bots accessing your contact page and using it to send spam mail or fill up you DB.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Store it in a database and give your support team a lookup page.